Proof or Citation that standard Borel spaces contain singletons
Suppose $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{B}(\mathsf{X}))$ is a standard Borel space. I have read that then all singletons $\{x\}$ with $x\in\mathsf{X}$ are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathsf{X})$. I cannot find a proper reference and I cannot seem to prove this fact.

I have read it here on page 2.

Proof:
$$
(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{B}(\mathsf{X})) \text{ standard} \implies \exists \text{ metric } d_\mathsf{X} \text{ s.t. } (\mathsf{X}, d_\mathsf{X}) \text{ metric space and inducing topology } \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{X}  
$$
$$
(\mathsf{X}, d_\mathsf{X}) \text{ metric space }  \implies \forall x\neq y, \exists U_x=\mathbb{B}_{d(x,y)/3}(x), V_y=\mathbb{B}_{d(x,y)/3}(y) \text{ s.t. } U_x\cap V_y = \emptyset
$$

By definition of standard Borel space the $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a metrizable topology, and all singletons are closed in a metric space

@AlessandroCodenotti Thank you. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set#:~:text=Singleton%20points%20(and%20thus%20finite,1%20spaces%20and%20Hausdorff%20spaces.&text=is%20an%20infinite%20and%20unbounded%20closed%20set%20in%20the%20real%20numbers) they say that indeed singletons are closed sets in a Hausdorff topological space (which should be true in our case too). Do you have a reference for the fact that ${x}$ are closed in a metric space?

Metric spaces are Hausdorff, since any two distinct points $x,y$ of a metric space are separate by the open balls of radius $d(x,y)/3$ centered in $x$ and $y$ respectively

@AlessandroCodenotti thank you! One more thing if you don't mind. The proof through the notion of Hausdorff space is nice and simple. Do you know if it possible to prove it directly from the fact that it is a metric space?

Sure, for each $n>0$ let $B(x,1/n)$ be the closure of the open ball of radius $1/n$ centered at $x$. Then ${x}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} B(x,1/n)$ is closed, being an intersection of closed sets

There is a complete metric $d$ on $\mathsf X$ making it a separable metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathsf X)$. In a metric space the singletons are closed sets, and therefore elements of $\mathcal B(\mathsf X)$, because this $\sigma$-algebra contains all open sets (and therefore also their complements).

Of possible interest: Harley/McNulty, When is a point Borel?, Pacific Journal of Mathematics 80 #1 (January 1979), 151-157 (freely available on the internet).
